# Retrofit 2.0 nested json with different subtypes

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

I am using retrofit 2.0 and gson to convert a json to a pojo.
I got following json object

```
{
"type": "champion",
"format": "standAloneComplex",
"version": "9.6.1",
"data": {
    "Aatrox": {...},
    "Ahri": {...},
     ...       
} }
```

my problem is that inside data each entry is a new class(it is the same class but different named)

i can access each class seperate

```
public class Champions {

@SerializedName("type")
@Expose
public String type;
@SerializedName("format")
@Expose
public String format;
@SerializedName("version")
@Expose
public String version;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
public Data data;
```

this works

```
public class Data {
@SerializedName("Aatrox")
@Expose
public Champion aatrox;
@SerializedName("Ahri")
@Expose
public Champion ahri;}
```

but

```
public class Data {
publc List<Champion> champions = new ArrayList<>();
```

doesnt

how can i get all the entries in a list?

I tried to put a `List<Champion>` in `Data` but i dont know what to put in `@SerializedName`.

Any suggestions how to retrieve a `List<Champion>` out of data?

the site i get the json from is http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.6.1/data/en_US/champion.json

Comment: If you are already getting the list form of your JSON response, directly put it into http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and download the appropriate data classes. The required formatting and classes, subclasses and collections all will be in it. Just add those classes to your project and start using them.

Comment: @MDNaseemAshraf i have done that and came up with what i posted here it generated a Class for each champion avaliable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set your `data` variable datatype `Map<String, Champion>` instead of setting it `object` or `List` and add below getter method into your model to retrieve `List<Champion>`

```
public List<Champion> getChampions(){
    if(data != null){
        return new ArrayList<Value>(data.values());
    }
    return null; // you can set return new ArrayList<>(); to avoid null exception 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a code like in my project. Maybe it will work. Arrange by yourself.

```
 Map<String, Champion> championList;
 List<String> keyset = new ArrayList<>(championList.keySet());
 List<String> values = new ArrayList<>(championList.values());

  for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
                        NewItem item = new NewItem(values.get(i), keyset.get(i));}
```